# Error Updating a record

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I get a mysql error:

**#update (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid) "Mysql::Error: #HY000Got error 139 from storage engine:**

When trying to update a text field on a record with a string of length 1429 characters, any ideas on how to track down the problem?

Below is the stacktrace.

```
from /var/www/releases/20081002155111/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:147:in `log'
from /var/www/releases/20081002155111/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:299:in `execute'
from /var/www/releases/20081002155111/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:167:in `update_sql'
from /var/www/releases/20081002155111/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:314:in `update_sql'
from /var/www/releases/20081002155111/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:49:in `update_without_query_dirty'
from /var/www/releases/20081002155111/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:19:in `update'
from /var/www/releases/20081002155111/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb:2481:in `update_without_lock'
from /var/www/releases/20081002155111/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/locking/optimistic.rb:70:in `update_without_dirty'
from /var/www/releases/20081002155111/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/dirty.rb:137:in `update_without_callbacks'
from /var/www/releases/20081002155111/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:234:in `update_without_timestamps'
from /var/www/releases/20081002155111/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:38:in `update'
from /var/www/releases/20081002155111/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb:2472:in `create_or_update_without_callbacks'
from /var/www/releases/20081002155111/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:207:in `create_or_update'
from /var/www/releases/20081002155111/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb:2200:in `save_without_validation'
from /var/www/releases/20081002155111/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/validations.rb:901:in `save_without_dirty'
from /var/www/releases/20081002155111/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/dirty.rb:75:in `save_without_transactions'
from /var/www/releases/20081002155111/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:106:in `save'
from /var/www/releases/20081002155111/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:66:in `transaction'
from /var/www/releases/20081002155111/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:79:in `transaction'
from /var/www/releases/20081002155111/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:98:in `transaction'
from /var/www/releases/20081002155111/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:106:in `save'
from /var/www/releases/20081002155111/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:118:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
from /var/www/releases/20081002155111/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:106:in `save'
```

Comment: What is the column type that you're trying to update?

Comment: Yeah, I few more details would probably help!

Comment: It's a text column in mysql, to be honest if the error wasn't so cryptic I might have solved this one out myself by now. Table might be corrupt or something, as it only effects one record in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's this bug: [#1030 - Got error 139 from storage engine](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=10035), but it would help if you'd post the query which should come directly after the error message.

Comment: The query doesn't get logged in the terminal, will hunt down the mysql logs. And as for the mysql ticket, I'm only updating one text field with a string of length 1429, surely it can handle that (can't it!?)?

Comment: The app is in production and the logs just show the above stack trace. I cannot duplicate the problem in development

Answer (score 1):

When you say a text field, is it of type VARCHAR, or TEXT?

If its the former then you cannot store a string larger than 255 chars (possibly less with UTF-8 overhead) in that column. If its the latter, you'd better post your schema definition so people can assist you further.

Answer (score 0):

It seemed to be a very weird mysql error, where the text was being truncated to 256 characters (for a text type) and throwing the above error is the string was 1000 characters or more. modifying the table column to be text again fixed the issue, or it just fixed it self.. i'm still not sure.

Update:
Changing the table type to MyISAM fixed this problem